# Use try-catch to avoid lengthy null checking?

Tags: java

In my code I have something like this

```
// 1st method
if (a == null) {
    return false;
}
if (a.getB() == null {
    return false;
}
if (a.getB().getC() == null {
    reutrn false;
}
return a.getB.getC().isFoo();
```

Which is clear but very wordy. Meanwhile, something like this is less wordy but maybe not as clear because it's using a try-catch in a nontraditional manner.

```
// 2nd method
try {
    return a.getB().getC().isFoo();
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Is there any reason to specifically not use the 2nd method, is it a bad practice? As an aside, is there any reason one should be used or is preferred over the other?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use exceptions for flow control control (it's a known anti-pattern). Read more here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: They are not even semantically equivalent: the second version would quietly mask any NPEs that `getB()`, `getC()` and `isFoo()` might throw. That could lead to some fun debugging sessions.

Comment: @NPE This is a good point, perhaps I should have put the assumption in the question that this wouldn't happen (although in practice this is not a good assumption)

Comment: @CaptainMan: As you point out, that's not a good assumption, mainly because it forces a contract upon `getB()`, `getC()`, `isFoo()` *as well as any other functions those three might call*.

Comment: My preference would be to put all the `if` conditions on one line like `if (a == null || a.getB() == null || a.getB().getC() == null ) {`.

Comment: Java 8 style: `return Optional.ofNullable(a).map(TypeOfA::getB).map(TypeOfB::getC).map(TypeOfC::isFoo).orElse(false);`

Comment: @Holger Much as I like some of the new goodies in Java 8, I feel that is WAY less readable than either of the OP's original choices, or my alternative.

Comment: @ David Wallace: You can also use `return Optional.ofNullable(a).map(x->x.getB()).map(x->x.getC()).map(x->x.isFoo())‌​.orElse(false);` and, of course, format it better in your source code than I can in the comments.

Comment: Why is the 2nd method considered flow control? The goal is to see if foo is true or not, so in the exceptional case that a, b, or c doesn't exist we catch it and return false. Would your answer differ if it were `return a.b.c.foo;`? I agree that exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control, I am just having trouble understanding why this is an example of flow control.